# Script in Visual Studio that tells about the changes in GUI

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on Visual Studio. I make changes in the GUI of VS like the one we have when we goto the properties of a VS project. I want to know that whether there are any scripts in VS with the help of which all the changes that i make in the in-built GUI of VS get stored in one script and if i deploy that script on another machine then same changes will get reflected in the same project on other machine too. I have heard there is one but cannot find it over the net. Has anyone come across any such thing?

Answer (score 1):

The properties of a VS project are store in a .SLN file , you should be able to copy that to another PC and have the changes reflected fine there.

If the changes you are referring to are in Visual Studio itself then you can export your settings by going to Tools -> Import And Export Settings.

As for detecting the changes the simplest way is to make sure that the files are in a SCR so that changes can be compared.

The other option is to write a little command line app that uses the FileSystemWatcher to monitor the directory in which your project is located. And then alert you when a change is detected.

Comment: Macros are stored externally use need to save them from the editor or better yet just create a macro project